# Amazon SQS messages coming through boto garbled

Tags: python, boto, amazon-sqs

I'm using a service that publishes messages to Amazon SQS, but my messages come out garbled when I do the following in Python, via boto:

```
queue = SQS_CONNECTION.get_queue(QUEUE_NAME)
messages = queue.get_messages()
```

The messages are returned as strings of what appear to be base 64 encoded data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As helped by this discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boto-users/Pv5fUc_RdVU ,
the solution is as follows:

```
from boto.sqs.message import RawMessage

queue = SQS_CONNECTION.get_queue(QUEUE_NAME)
queue.set_message_class(RawMessage)
messages = queue.get_messages()
```